# How fetch icons google material design from website?

Tags: android

In json I got response with name icon for example "icon: "camera_roll", the all icons are from built-in library android, how I can parse string to image?

Comment: you can't, you'll probably have to use those string names in another api request to retrieve the icons themselves

Comment: add some example of json to clarify the issue

Answer (score 0):

For convert string to image you can use these codes:

```
 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(content, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

content is your string